# How can I convert a PostScript file into a PDF where text can be selected?

Tags: macos, pdf, ps

I'm on a Mac. I need text to be selectable in applications such as Preview.app, so that I can highlight it. If I open the PS file directly in Preview, I cannot select text.

I have already tried ps2pdf.

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search found [pstil](http://www.wizards.de/~frank/pstill.html) and [verydoc](http://www.verydoc.com/ps-to-pdf.html); one of those might help.  Of course, [Acrobat](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/creating-pdf-files-acrobat-x) is also offered.